# How to fix data load redundancy while loading data into mongodb using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb

I am loading my data into MongoDB using mongoimport command. While loading same data multiple times I came across a problem that my data is being loaded redundantly. How can I stop that redundancy using the automatic unique id variable that gets generated for each document? #mongodb

For Example, I want to load a csv with 200 entries but when I load the same file again the document count loaded becomes 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you create the collection first in the database using createCollection command and then create index on key that remains unique throughtout csv. 
Now if you import the data it will get added in collection but next time when you import same csv it will not be added because of unique key.

Comment: I am setting new index but when I am importing using mongoimport it again adds the same documents. Do I need to change my mongoimport command after that

Comment: I got my answer I have to make a capped collection in mongodb. Thanks for the help.